# how to i force UITableViewCell to keep its accessory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is a snippet of code I am using on my tableview `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
if ([[listOfQueOverview valueForKey:@"EXPENSEDETAILID"] containsObject:(_isDrilldown) ? cust.DETAILACCT : listOfOverview[0] ACCOUNTNUMBER) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
} else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

this allows me to toggle the accessory when tapping the cell. Problem i have is when dequeueing a cell, the accessory resets to none. how can i force it to keep the checkmark if i scrolled with a checkmark on that particular cell

Comment: you can just create a data structure that remembers the index paths that should have checkmarks. When dequeueing, you can't be guaranteed you're reusing a cell that has a certain accessory type so you just need to have a structure that remembers which index paths should have checkmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following. Whenever a user taps a checkmark to set UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark, add the row to the `checkedIndices` array as follows: `[checkedIndices addObject:@(indexPath.row)];`

In your class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *checkedIndices;

// ....

self.checkedIndices = [@[]mutableCopy];

// ....

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    if ([checkedIndices containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```